# Upper bound on expected maximum difference between two scalar products involving uniform random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, expected-value

I am faced with a following problem. Assume two vectors $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\tau$ entries being either $-1$ or $1$ and the rest $0$. I want to calculate the following quantity:
$$\max_{u \in \mathbb{R}^n\\ ||u||_{\infty} \leq 2} \langle v_1, u \rangle - \langle v_2, u \rangle $$

Or at least an upper bound on the expected value. How would I approach such a problem? Is there anything similar from which I could take inspiration?

Comment: You could first simplify to $\|v_1-v_2\|_{\ell^1}$.